# Fix bootloader after removing Ubuntu from a dual boot system?

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, bootloader

I have installed a Ubuntu alongside Pre-installed Windows-8...
And now I have uninstalled Ubuntu. But the problem is that after removing Ubuntu and typing "bootrec/Fixmbr" in Command Prompt, there is still showing a boot manager with only one option Windows-8. How can I get rid of this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What boot manager appears? The Windows boot manager? If so, you can try the one of the following methods. (The first one is probably easier.)

Basically, you need to tell the Windows Boot Manager to boot the Windows Boot Loader by default (unless it's already doing this), and then tell the Windows Boot Manager to stop displaying the boot menu.

*Please note that if you make a mistake during this process, you may no longer be able to boot into Windows. If this happens, your best bet may be to boot into a Windows disc and use the recovery options there. Especially in the case that you were using Method 2, you can even open a command prompt from the disc and try using BCDEdit again.*

## Method 1: Control Panel Options

1. Open the Control Panel (Start -> Control Panel)
2. Go to "System and Security"
3. Go to "System"
4. Go to "Advanced System Settings"
5. Go to the "Advanced" tab
6. Under "Startup and Recovery", click "Settings"
7. Under "System Startup" -> "Default operating system", choose something like "Windows 8"
8. Uncheck the option "Time to display list of operating systems". You'll notice that the number of seconds changes to 0.

I found some of the information for Method 1 here: [How to change Windows 7 Boot manager options to start the OS automatically?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-change-windows-7-boot-manager-options-to/0d5f2508-a70f-4a3a-a10c-4388a1acc34b)

## Method 2: BCDEdit

BCDEdit is a built-in utility in Windows Vista, 7, & 8 that you should also be able to use to solve your problem.

### 1) Make sure Windows is your default boot entry.

1. In Windows, open a command prompt. (e.g. Hold the Windows key and press `R`.
2. In the "Run" window that appears, type `cmd` and press `Enter`.)
3. In the command prompt, run the command `bcdedit` to display current boot information. There should be an entry called "**Windows Boot Loader**" (NOT "Windows Boot *Manager*"!) followed by a line with "identifier" and a long string of characters enclosed by { }. This string is the GUID (or just "id" or "identifier") of that boot entry.
4. Run the command `BCDEdit /default id`, where where you replace `id` with the long identifier of the Windows boot entry, to make that boot loader the default one.

### 2) Skip the boot menu so you no longer see it.

Use the following BCDEdit command to skip the boot menu so you don't see it:
`bcdedit /timeout 0`.
In this command, `0` is actually the number of seconds the Windows  to display the boot selection screen.

I found some of the information for Method 2 here:

[BCDEdit Command-Line Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Changing the Default Boot Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It is a Windows boot manager.I have an Easy BC.Can you please suggest me the way through it?Because I am not used to with Command Line.

Comment: Please see my revised answer above. I added a way to access boot manager settings from the Control Panel (just discovered this) and added more detail to the BCDEdit instructions.

Alternatively, if you want to use EasyBCD (as you mentioned), I would recommend looking for instructions in the program itself or on their website. I don't have EasyBCD, so I can't guide you through that.

Comment: I have done with Easy BCD,and thnx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows installation DVD or repair CD, you can boot to a repair command prompt and run:(repair/advanced/cmdprompt)
enter:
bootrec /fixmbr
This command installs the Windows bootloader. If you have a dual boot it would boot straight to Windows and you can then do what you want with the linux partitions.
That worked for me.